# How to prevent html elements with higher z-index catch events

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, z-index

I´m developing a little Chrome extension to allow user see what they are typing. It's a simple semi-transparent floating div element. The problem that I have is that html elements under it don't receive click events because the div element is over them (> z-index).

My question is:
Is any way to make my div "transparent" for click events (and other type of events)?

An image:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the CSS rule 'pointer-events'.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: +1 did't know about that! although it doesn't look like its supported very well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: But he is developing a chrome extension

Comment: @user2330441 its just a warning for visitors.